# How to prevent a user from deleting an entity referenced node before deleting the referencing (child) node first?

Tags: 7

I have a Content Type called `ItemRequest`, and another Content Type called `ItemOrder`. One of the fields in `ItemOrder` is "Related Item Request" that is an Entity Reference to `ItemRequest`. Each `ItemOrder` has at least one Related Item Request.

How do I ensure that a parent `ItemRequest` node can only be deleted if it does not have any `ItemOrder` nodes relating to it? What hook can I use that can test for the existence of these child nodes and call form_set_error to abandon node deletion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [hook_node_access](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/7.x):

> Modules may implement this hook if they want to have a say in whether
>   or not a given user has access to perform a given operation on a node.

The second parameter for this hook is $op:

> $op: The operation to be performed. Possible values:
>
> "create" "delete" "update" "view"

And the return values are:

- NODE_ACCESS_ALLOW: if the operation is to be allowed.
- NODE_ACCESS_DENY: if the operation is to be denied.
- NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE: to not affect this operation at all.

So, you should implement that hook, check if the node being deleted is of type `ItemRequest` and if yes collect all the ItemOrder that point to it. If none are collected you can return `NODE_ACCESS_IGNORE`, if there're `ItemOrder` pointing to the `ItemRequest` return `NODE_ACCESS_DENY`.

While you can hook into the node form and add a custom validator that doesn't prevent user to delete the node using other means (admin content view, for example). This method can prevent any action trying to delete a node.